# Searching for an integer in arraylist in java

Tags: java

```
public class FindNumber {

            static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
                String res = "YES";
    //Unable to identify problem with this part of the code
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                    if (k == arr.get(i))
                        res = "YES";
                    else
                        res = "NO";

                }

                return res;

            }
}
```

Above code returns NO as the answer even if the integer is present in the list.

Comment: Using `==` to compare Integer objects only works if the values are between `-128` and `127`, all other values will need to be compared using the `.equals()` method instead

Comment: there are several things wrong with your code. If you want true or false, return a boolean (for instance)

Comment: @JonK there is no comparison between Integer objects. The comparison is between Integer object and int primitive. Integer object is auto unboxed in this case.

Comment: @THe_strOX Absolutely correct, and that's why it's a comment instead of an answer. It's quite an easy gotcha to get bitten by when you're first starting out, so I feel it's still worth mentioning.

Comment: @JonK That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
            String res = "YES";
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (k == arr.get(i))
                    res = "YES";
                    break;
                else
                    res = "NO";

            }

            return res;

        }
```

Once you find the integer you have to stop the loop, and you can do this using a `break`

Comment: if you want to go for a fix like that, you should have just replaced the whole if else with if ( found ) return "YES";

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `arr.contains()` to get a boolean value of whether `Integer` is on the list or not. An then you can translate this value to `YES` or `NO` (if you do really need it):

```java
String yesNo = arr.contains(k) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

Comment: or, change the returntype to boolean and say: return arr.contains(k);

Answer (score 0):

try optimize your code....

way 1 (using for-each loop):

```
 static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) { 
        for (Integer integer : arr) {
            if (integer == k) {
                return "YES";
            }
        }
        return "NO"; 
    }
```

another way is (using ternary operator) :

```
static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) { 
    return arr.contains(k) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams:

```
static String findNumber(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
    return arr.stream()
        .filter(e -> e == k)
        .findFirst()
        .map(e -> "YES")
        .orElse("NO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String isListContainsNumber(List<Integer> nums, int n) {
           return nums.stream().anyMatch(el -> el.equals(n)) ? "YES" : "NO";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that even if it finds an integer object in the ArrayList, after setting res = Yes, it still continues the iteration. Therefore there is a possibility that there might be other values inside the list of not the desired data type, thereby setting res back to No.
The solution here is to use a jump statement such as break which would terminate the loop process as soon as an integer is encountered.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks :) .. jump statement is something i missed. Adding "break" after return "YES" solved the issue.